# Missing ldapPublicKey on bitname/openldap

Tags: openldap

I have an openldap server running from truecharts/openldap, there I have ldapPublicKey:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.1.5.5:389 -x -s base -b "cn=subschema" objectclasses|grep -i ldapPublicKey 
objectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 NAME 'ldapPublicKey' DESC 'MAND
```

and I can add the sshPublicKey attribute to user's accounts.

However, when running the bitname/openldap image, I seem to be missing this object class:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://localhost:1389 -x -s base -b "cn=subschema" objectclasses|grep -i ldapPublicKey
```

^returns nothing.  However, when I remove the grep, there are an assortment of the usual classes.  Why am I missing ldapPublicKey?  Is this some sort of custom ldif I need to be adding in?  It seems like it should be pretty standard.

EDIT: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues/49722) with bitnami in the hopes of getting some more eyes on this.